# Custom reveal effect is showing below the WebView Android not revealing the web view

Tags: android, webview, circularreveal

I am using Circular Reveal Library (ttps://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal) to reveal view in an activity containing web view, this animation works without any problem but it is drawing below the web view. The `WebView` does not revealed with its parent view, and when I add some animations to `WebView` then this cancels the circular reveal animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/myCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:contentPadding="5dp">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/myWeb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/myCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:contentPadding="5dp">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/myWeb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>
```

Comment: I think you have duplicated your xml. You cannot have two root views in the same xml

Comment: Have you tried setting the `height` of the  `WebView` to be `match_parent`

Comment: @Darpan Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is using an AnimatorListener that toggles the visibility of the WebView:

```
WebView webView = ...

Animator circularReveal = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal( ... )
circularReveal.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
        webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    }
}
```